# How to capture method parameters passed via lambda?

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, func

I have a generic method in Web API base controller to which I pass in a Func
I'd like to somehow, if possible, to caputre parameters of the callback method used within lambda...

To illustrate see following code

```
public class StuffController : BaseController
{
    // method #1
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetWidget(int id)
    {
        return await ProcessRestCall(async rc => await rc.GetWidgetAsync(id));
    }

    // method #2
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetWidget(int year, int periodId, int modelId, int sequenceId)
    {
        return await ProcessRestCall(async rc => await rc.GetWidgetAsync(year, periodId, modelId, sequenceId));
    }

    // method #3
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DecodeWidget(string sid)
    {
        return await ProcessRestCall(async rc => await rc.GetIdsAsync(sid));
    }
}


public class BaseController : ApiController
{
    [NonAction]
    protected async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ProcessRestCall<T>(Func<RestClient, Task<T>> restClientCallback) where T : class
    {
        // stuff happens...

        // TODO: here I'd like to capture parameters (and their types) of the await methods passed to restClientCallback via lambdas...
        // for example, in case of method #2 I would  get params object [] containing year, periodId, modelId, sequenceId
        T result = await restClientCallback(restClient);

        // more stuff...
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);        
        return response;
    }
}
```

### Update ("Why are doing this?")

The `ProcessRestCall` method above does many things but mainly it does login, get data, log out...I have a simple, small memory cache that I wanted to use after login to return the data and improve performance. I do not have control over "rest client" and how it behaves. My WidgetCache wraps System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache and uses "typeof(T)-id(-id)*" as a string cache key. to generate cache key I need type of result (which I have), and 1 or more related ids (which are being passed as params within labbda callback)

### Possible Workaround (maybe even cleaner approach)

I could capture this data and send it as a parameter to `ProcessRestCall`

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetWidget(int id)
{
    var cacheKey = Cache.GenerateKeyFor(typeof(Widget), id);
    return await ProcessRestCall(async rc => await rc.GetWidgetAsync(id), cacheKey);
}
```

Comment: This is real code smell.  Why do you need this information?  What do you plan to do with it?  There seems like a much more effective design to solve your problem.

Comment: @Servy see Update section above...